# Skip Input Command?

Tags: java

How can I have the program check for input and if no input is received the program will just skip over the command.
I'm trying to make a game and was curious if anything like that existed.

Comment: More details please! How are you reading the input? What does it look like if you get no input? Maybe an empty string? Then just check if the string is empty and skip.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Answer (score 1):

Just simple as follows

```
if(input!=null){
   // execute

}else{
  // skip
}
```

Assume your input will be a `Scanner` input via command prompt. Then you have to wait for user input. Then check(validate) user input. if input not `null` or `empty` you can proceed else you can skip.